# Failed to load signer on Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Using Xamarin.Android 10.3 I'm trying to sign a Release package from Visual Studio 16.6.5. In order not to include the password as plaintext on the csproj file, I've added a file in the project folder called Pass.txt and exluded it in the git.ignore file

[image]

But when it comes to the signing process it fails with:

> Failed to load signer "signer #1"
> java.io.IOException: Failed to read Key "myapp" password for signer #1 : end of file reached in C:\Users\myuser\source\repos\MyApp.Xamarin\Pass.txt

If I remove the `file:Pass.txt` and past the password it works fine.

According to [this release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/10/10.1) we can use `file:` in Xamarin 10.1 an later.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AndroidSigningStorePass>file:C:\Users\Windows User\AndroidSigningPassword.txt</AndroidSigningStorePass>
  <AndroidSigningKeyPass>file:C:\Users\Windows User\AndroidSigningPassword.txt</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Hmm interesting, perhaps a permissions issue?

Comment: The exception says "end of file reached" so the file must have been opened at least, and the password is in the file, definetly.

Comment: @FritjofBerggren How is your file structured? The error is saying it did not find the key "myapp", i.e. it is in key/value format (dictionary),

Comment: I just realized I had to put the password twice if the file is being used for the 2 entries

Comment: Note that if the same file is specified for both settings, the file must contain two lines. The first line must be the keystore password, and the second line must be the alias password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missed "Note that if the same file is specified for both settings, the file must contain two lines. The first line must be the keystore password, and the second line must be the alias password. – Fritjof Berggren just now"

Adding the password twice on the file fixed it

Comment: Hi ,glad solved that ! Remember to mark it when you have time , it will be helpful for other people to know the solution later. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the issue just fixes and you well never know how.
This is what I did and it is fixed.

1. Goto Tools>> Android >> Android ADB Command Prompt
2. Type **`C:\Android\SDK>adb remove {your Package Name}`**
3. `Clean Project`
4. Build in `Release Mode`

after that clean and rebuild in `Debug mode`.

Answer (score 1):

For me this issue was that I have the folder in One Drive and I have set the option for saving space, so I just have the link in my machine,as soon as I download the file, it works

Answer (score -1):

Feb 2024: I had the same problem and had to change

OLD:

```
<propertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android34.0|AnyCPU'">
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>xxxxx</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <ApplicationId>com.aaaaa.bbbbb</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

TO:

```
<propertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android34.0|AnyCPU'">
    <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>xxxxx</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>xxxxx</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <ApplicationId>com.aaaaa.bbbbb</ApplicationId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The line with AndroidSigningKeyPass (!) was missing.